# PHP Change my Array Format

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the $_POST array like this:

```
 'UserChildren' => 
  array (
    'child_name' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Ram',
      1 => 'Shyam',
    ),
    'child_birth_date' => 
    array (
      0 => '2005-03-30',
      1 => '2007-06-15',
    ),
    'child_gender' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Male',
      1 => 'Male',
    ),
  ),
)
```

I want to convert the above array result like this for saving it to database:

```
'UserChildren' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'child_name' => string 'Ram' (length=3)
          'child_birth_date' => string '2005-03-30' (length=10)
          'child_gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'child_name' => string 'Shyam' (length=3)
          'child_birth_date' => string '2007-06-15' (length=10)
          'child_gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)

Update:

foreach($_POST['UserChildren']['child_name'] as $key => $val) {
   $userchild->child_name = $val;
   $userchild->child_birth_date = $_POST['UserChildren']['child_birth_date'][$key];
  $userchild->child_gender = $_POST['UserChildren']['child_gender'][$key];
}

  $userchild->save();
  print_r($userchild->getErrors());
```

Comment: Wow. Amazing that after 100 questions you still have no idea what a question looks like. Nor have the decency to at least proof read your title.

Comment: By now you should know at [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing the form inputs like this will give the desired array:

```
<input type="text" name="UserChildren[0][child_name]">
<input type="text" name="UserChildren[0][child_bith_date]">
<input type="text" name="UserChildren[0][child_gender]">

<input type="text" name="UserChildren[1][child_name]">
<input type="text" name="UserChildren[1][child_bith_date]">
<input type="text" name="UserChildren[1][child_gender]">
```

With your existing array just loop one array and access the other arrays using the common key:

```
foreach($_POST['UserChildren']['child_name'] as $key => $val) {
    $name   = $val;
    $birth  = $_POST['UserChildren']['child_birth_date'][$key];
    $gender = $_POST['UserChildren']['child_gender'][$key];
}
```

Comment: I tried your example, I am able to save only the first value. updating the question with the exact code.

Comment: The sql generated is like `INSERT INTO `user_children` (`user_id`, `child_name`, `child_birth_date`, `child_gender`) VALUES (73, 'Shyam', '2007-06-15', 'Male')`

Comment: Maybe an array `$userchild->child_name[] = $val;`.  I don't know your DB API so I can't tell.

Comment: I rechecked it. It is actually saving the last record from foreach, it is ignoring the previous ones.

Comment: OK, see my previous comment.